# Getting error below while running rails server on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

OptionParser::AmbiguousOption: ambiguous option: -b0.0.0.0
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: b
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in`'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: put a space after `-b` in `-b0.0.0.0`

Comment: Where is this OptionParser command line located?

Comment: I hope I had those magical powers to know your code errors, but unfortunately, I don't. [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).